# Specifying style on WMS maplibre

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld, maplibre-gl

I am trying to visualise a WMS layer on maplibre the layer comes from GeoServer, the code that works in Leaflet is as follows

```
var wmsLayertest = L.tileLayer.wms('http://139.84.229.39:8080/geoserver/wms?', {
    layers: 'Landinvestment_datasets:Cranberry_Crop Production_Crop Suitability',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    styles:'Crop Production_Crop Suitability_Cranberry_Zomba',
    crs:L.CRS.EPSG4326
}).addTo(map);
```

So the crs part on the above code helps to visualize.

The part below shows my implementation with maplibre that fails to work when I add styles on the URL

```
var test_geoserver = ("http://139.84.229.39:8080/geoserver/wms?bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}"+
    "&format=image/png&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=Landinvestment_datasets:"+
    "Cranberry_Crop Production_Crop Suitability&width=256&height=256&transparent=true"+
    "&crs=EPSG:3857&styles=Crop Production_Crop Suitability_Cranberry_Zomba")
```

Comment: What does `{bbox-epsg-3857}` evaluate to?  You may also need to replace spaces in layer and styles with `%20`

Comment: @nmtoken the ```{bbox-epsg-3857}``` gives it the projection that maplibre can use to visualize, tried to add the %20 where there are spaces but doesnt seen to work

Comment: Yes, but what are the values in the request sent to the server, because if they are wrong you won't get a map and that might be the root cause of your issue.  If they are not important to the issue you could substitute coordinates that you expect to work,

Comment: a request like this works for me: `http://139.84.229.39:8080/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=3636977.415120216552,-1627670.827034762362,3998044.74385648733,-1329544.969493945828&CRS=EPSG:3857&WIDTH=688&HEIGHT=567&LAYERS=Landinvestment_datasets%3ACranberry_Crop%20Production_Crop%20Suitability&STYLES=Landinvestment_datasets%3Acropsuitability_canbery_2zKeruX&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE`  That's with encoded spaces and colons.  I think though your issue is you are calling a style that doesn't exist (according to the GetCapabilities response)

Comment: Seems like the issue is maplibre does not support sld that has ogc function for cropshape, if i remove the ogc function from the sld and specify the style it works